# How to "reads" into a Scala Case Class given a Json object with key names that start with a capital letter

Tags: scala, play-json

This question is based upon Scala 2.12.12

```scala
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"
```

using play-json

```scala
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.9.1"
```

If I have a Json object that looks like this:

```json
{
   "UpperCaseKey": "some value", 
   "AnotherUpperCaseKey": "some other value" 
}
```

I know I can create a case class like so:

```scala
case class Yuck(UpperCaseKey: String, AnotherUpperCaseKey: String)
```

and follow that up with this chaser:

```scala
implicit val jsYuck = Json.format[Yuck]
```

and that will, of course, give me both `reads[Yuck]` and `writes[Yuck]` to and from Json.

I'm asking this because I have a use case where I'm not the one deciding the case of the keys and I've being handed a Json object that is full of keys that start with an uppercase letter.

In this use case I will have to read and convert millions of them so performance is a concern.

I've looked into @JsonAnnotations and Scala's transformers. The former doesn't seem to have much documentation for use in Scala at the field level and the latter seems to be a lot of boilerplate for something that might be very simple another way if I only knew how...

Bear in mind as you answer this that some Keys will be named like this:

```
XXXYyyyyZzzzzz
```

So the predefined Snake/Camel case conversions will not work.

Writing a custom conversion seems to be an option yet unsure how to do that with Scala.

Is there a way to arbitrarily request that the Json read will take Key `"XXXYyyyZzzz"` and match it to a field labeled `"xxxYyyyZzzz"` in a Scala case class?

Just to be clear I may also need to convert, or at least know how, a Json key named `"AbCdEf"` into field labeled `"fghi"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way play-json support such a scenario, is defining your own `Format`.

Let's assume we have:

```scala
case class Yuck(xxxYyyyZzzz: String, fghi: String)
```

So we can define `Format` on the companion object:

```scala
object Yuck {
  implicit val format: Format[Yuck] = {
    ((__ \ "XXXYyyyZzzz").format[String] and (__ \ "AbCdEf").format[String]) (Yuck.apply(_, _), yuck => (yuck.xxxYyyyZzzz, yuck.fghi))
  }
}
```

Then the following:

```scala
val jsonString = """{ "XXXYyyyZzzz": "first value", "AbCdEf": "second value" }"""
val yuck = Json.parse(jsonString).validate[Yuck]
println(yuck)
yuck.map(yuckResult => Json.toJson(yuckResult)).foreach(println)
```

Will output:

```scala
JsSuccess(Yuck(first value,second value),)
{"XXXYyyyZzzz":"first value","AbCdEf":"second value"}
```

As we can see, `XXXYyyyZzzz` was mapped into `xxxYyyyZzzz` and `AbCdEf` into `fghi`.

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/f7asd6CuSW2Ulik1OuggBg).

Another option you have, is to usd `JsonNaming`, as @cchantep suggested in the comment. If you define:

```
object Yuck {
  val keysMap = Map("xxxYyyyZzzz" -> "XXXYyyyZzzz", "fghi" -> "AbCdEf")
  implicit val config = JsonConfiguration(JsonNaming(keysMap))
  implicit val fotmat = Json.format[Yuck]
}
```

Running the same code will output the same. Code ru nat [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GMoARUxXRW6TbjSaokipJg).

Comment: The JsonNaming approach looks way way more self-explanatory and maintainable. Question: Does one have to define ALL keys or only the exceptions this way? Could it be mixed/matched with the CamelCase/PascalCase/SnakeCase conversion methods? (Say 10 keys with 2 needing exceptions and 8 could flow through with PascalCase?).

Comment: @Techmag, you need to define all keys, because behind the scenes play transforms this map into an apply method. Therefore if there is a mismatch in the values count it won't compile. I don't think you can mix it in with any of the `Case` conversions, but if you think about it, it doesn't make sense to use both. Just create the mapping as you want it, instead of creating the map camel cased and then transform it to pascal case, or the other way around.

Comment: I was only thinking of the combination in the case where you did not have to supply all the keys. If all keys are required then yes multiple transformations would make no sense. Thank you for the clarity on this.

Answer (score 3):

Just use provided `PascalCase`.

```
case class Yuck(
  upperCaseKey: String,
  anotherUpperCaseKey: String)

object Yuck {
  import play.api.libs.json._

  implicit val jsonFormat: OFormat[Yuck] = {
    implicit val cfg = JsonConfiguration(naming = JsonNaming.PascalCase)

    Json.format
  }
}

play.api.libs.json.Json.parse("""{
   "UpperCaseKey": "some value", 
   "AnotherUpperCaseKey": "some other value" 
}""").validate[Yuck]
// => JsSuccess(Yuck(some value,some other value),)

play.api.libs.json.Json.toJson(Yuck(
  upperCaseKey = "foo",
  anotherUpperCaseKey = "bar"))
// => JsValue = {"UpperCaseKey":"foo","AnotherUpperCaseKey":"bar"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example code -- that will be very useful for some other things I need to do. In this case however it only resolves the first letter, which at least gives me "better" fields names in the Scala Case Class. If does not however handle the ```XXXYyyyyZzzzzz``` which I would prefer to was converted to ```xxxYyyyyZzzzzz``` or the arbitrary ```XXXyyyyyZzzzzz``` which I would prefer to be ```xxxYyyyyZzzzzz```

Comment: You could replace `PascalCase` by whatever custom `JsonNaming` ... Aka a `String => String`